# How can I access a Wamp web app on another PC

Tags: localhost, wamp, wampserver, lan

I coded a website during my internship and wanted to deploy it on the enterprise's network.
The purpose is to connect to the website on other computers without installing wamp on each one.
On PC1 I have WAMP online, with the vhost file modified : "Require all granted"
But when on PC2 I search for ip_PC1/name_of_website nothing happen.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Which port is Your Wamp using? If you use 80 or 443 port check incoming/outgoing port settings or if you dont use 80 or 443 ports; search with port number like ip_PC1:8080/name_of_website

Comment: Hmm never thought WAMP was enterprise. ;)

Comment: I use port 80, how can I check incoming/outgoing port settings ?

Comment: If its a corportate network get the domain name added the the corporate DNS, then PC's will find your PC1 properly.